# Display data in two columns with UI Fabric React

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I would like to display data dynamically in 2 columns with UI Fabric React. For example I want to have 2 columns one for teachers and one for students, and each time I want to add an entry to one of these columns dynamically with code. These 2 columns should be aligned next to each other. How do we do this with Office UI Fabric? Knowing that the number of teachers and students might differ

Example Below:

```
Teachers               Students
Teacher1               Student1
Teacher2               Student2
Teacher3
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? To be precise, how you plan to populate columns?

Comment: What I tried to is to create a grid with rows, and keep adding rows. but the design isn't working well …

Comment: Can you provide working example or picture ?

Comment: Hi @MarkoSavic here is the problem that arises when using UI fabric with rows, I have pasted the generated HTML in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833297/floating-divs-on-a-new-line-not-acquiring-the-whole-space/64833517#64833517

Comment: if I use rows and one column is larger than others, the design won't work. Is there a way to do what I want with ui fabric?